# TypeError: context.guild.members.has is not a function(162:30)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was adding new features to my Discord Bot then suddenly the following problem has stopped me from completing my code !
***( What is my mistake ? Where is my mistake ? How can I solve it ? )***

**The Problem :** 
`TypeError: context.guild.members.has is not a function(162:30)`

**My Code :**

```
1:     const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
2:     const timedEvents = ["minute", "fiveMinutes", "fifteenMinutes", "halfAnHour", "hour", "day"];

157:   const getMember = context => {
158:       if (!context.member) {
159:           if (context.newMember)
160:               context.member = context.newMember;
161:           if (context.guild && context.user && !context.member)
162:               if (context.guild.members.has(context.user.id))
163:                   context.member = context.guild.members.get(context.user.id);
164:       }
165:   };
```

Comment: To answer where your mistake is - line 162

Comment: Is context.guild.members.has() a function you defined? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since discord.js v12, you need to use `cache` to access the `members` collection.

```js
const getMember = context => {
  if (!context.member) {
    if (context.newMember)
      context.member = context.newMember;
    if (context.guild && context.user && !context.member)
      if (context.guild.members.cache.has(context.user.id))
        context.member = context.guild.members.cache.get(context.user.id);
  }
};
```

Comment: Okay I'll Try :)